# ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified. when build hello world in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, esp32

I have followed esp-idf guideline to install and test to build the hello world and blink sample code but both the code met this problem.

[Visual studio try to build hello world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftKRs.png)

```
> Executing task: ninja  <

ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command ninja " terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I have tested all the ways I can find to fix it but I'm not sure anything I missed or not.

This is one of the way that I test but also met some problem.
[cmd try to run the command below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCGf8.png)

```
C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4>python -m pip install --user -r %IDF_PATH%/requirements.txt
    ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

This possible problem is the python environment is exist so I cannot do this command, but I try many ways to disabled or deactivated it still cannot.

[python path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ge8.png)

[system environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z4oR.png)

Answer (score 1):

After trying to debug this for a long time, I made a backup copy of the entire project folder, then just went hog-wild deleting files.  I deleted almost every file I didn't author.  Only left the `main/CMakeLists.txt`, `main/component.mk`, `main/main.c`, `main/main.h`, `.gitignore`, `CMakeLists.txt`, and `Makefile`.  Then I ran `idf.py set-target esp32` and `idf.py -p /dev/ttyACM0 flash monitor` and it worked fine again.

VS Code & ESP-IDF on Ubuntu 20.04.05 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Check if the compiler is properly selected. If you don't select a proper c/c++ compiler, then you might get this error. I had mingw in my system, but vs code did not auto detect the compiler. Then I manually added mingw and selected it for compilation after which this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after updating to the new stable release (v5.0) was

1. Go to the folder S:\esp\esp-idf\esp-idf-v5.0
2. Run command prompt at this directory and execute `install.bat` and later `export.bat`
3. After trying to build the program in VSCode the error "**ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja'**" shows up.
4. Update the path in the ESP-IDF extension in VSCode using `ESP-IDF:Configure Paths`
5. locate your project folder e.g. "V:\simpleTest_using_EspIDF_v5_0"
6. Open command prompt and execute: `idf.py build`
7. Now it builds also in VSCode using the Espressif IDF extension.

Answer (score 0):

Not having `ninja.build` present is a symptom of ninja not being built, which could be caused by several things.  For me this happened after I ran the commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg install openblas:x64-windows
```

```
Computing installation plan...
A suitable version of cmake was not found (required v3.29.0) Downloading portable cmake 3.29.0...
Downloading cmake...
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.29.0/cmake-3.29.0-windows-i386.zip->C:\Users\Michael Currie\Desktop\GitHub\vcpkg\downloads\cmake-3.29.0-windows-i386.zip
Downloading https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.29.0/cmake-3.29.0-windows-i386.zip
Extracting cmake..
```

**Problem 1**: It's downloading an i386 version of cmake!  But my computer is 64-bit!

```
PS C:\Users\Michael Currie> wmic os get osarchitecture
OSArchitecture
64-bit
```

Oh, `vcpkg`, you sweet summer child, please check the architecture of the computer before downloading `cmake` - you grabbed the wrong version!!

**Problem 2**: actually, I already had a cmake installed (version 3.26), and it was hogging the PATH, so even though vcpkg tried installing a new cmake, my old cmake was still being used even after the above attempt at installing 3.29.

So to fix these two issues:

- Start -> Run -> Add or Remove Programs -> uninstall old `cmake` 3.26, and
- Manually install the correct one at https://cmake.org/download/: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.29.0/cmake-3.29.0-windows-x86_64.zip

**Problem 3**: I needed to run the above commands in a PowerShell 7.0 or above. So I needed to:

- Install Powershell from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.16/PowerShell-7.2.16-win-x64.msi and then
- Manually run it from Start -> Run -> Powershell 7
- Check your version has Major >= 7 via the command `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`
- (note that you CANNOT uninstall Powershell 1.0 at C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 (it's not in Add or Remove Programs!), see https://superuser.com/questions/1503460/how-to-reinstall-powershell-on-windows-10)

**Problem 4** The problem still persisted, but according to https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/29702 I need to install Visual Studio version 2019 (NOT 2022 due to some bugs apparently), and select:

- Visual Studio English Language Pack.
- Visual Studio Desktop development with C++.
- Windows 10 SDK or Windows 11 SDK. (depending on your windows version)

After fixing the 4 problems above, I completely deleted the vcpkg folder from my computer, then ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg install openblas:x64-windows
```

again, and it worked!  openblas was built!  Yay!!

Answer (score -3):

You not have a `build.ninja` file. Find this file on proje

Comment: This file is auto-generated on each build by the ESP-IDF framework.  It's not a file that should be in the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).